# how to construct JSON from array

Tags: mysql, json, arduino-esp8266

i am trying to control some switches through my webserver and Nodemcu. i am managing to connect to my Database and read data.
I want to send data back to the server but i am not how to construct a JSON from an array.

This is my code :

```
if(currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    if ((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {
      outputsState = httpGETRequest(serverName);
      Serial.println("OutputState ( {ID Key:[Switch ID, State, Mode, AlarmON, AlarmOFF,JustChanged]}");
      Serial.println(outputsState);
      Serial.println(" ");

      JSONVar myObject = JSON.parse(outputsState);

      if (JSON.typeof(myObject) == "undefined") {
        Serial.println("Parsing input failed!");
        return;
      }

      JSONVar keys = myObject.keys();

      for (int i = 0; i < keys.length(); i++) {
        JSONVar value = myObject[keys[i]];

        Switch_ID[i]              = atoi(value[0]);
        Switch_Mode[i]            = atoi(value[1]);
        Switch_State[i]           = atoi(value[2]);
        Switch_AlarmOn[i]         = atoi(value[3]);
        Switch_AlarmOFF[i]        = atoi(value[4]);
        Switch_JustChanged[i]     = atoi(value[5]);

        if (Switch_Mode[i] == 0 && Switch_State[i] == 0 && Switch_JustChanged[i] == 0) {
              mySwitch315.send(Switch_ID[i], 24);
              New_State[i] = 1;
              New_JustChanged[i] = 1;
        }
        if (Switch_Mode[i] == 0 && Switch_State[i] == 1 && Switch_JustChanged[i] == 1) {
              mySwitch315.send(Switch_ID[i], 24);
              New_State[i] = 0;
              New_JustChanged[i] = 0;
        }
        if (Switch_Mode[i] == 1 && Switch_AlarmOn[i] == 1 && Switch_State[i] == 0 && Switch_JustChanged[i] == 0) {
              mySwitch315.send(Switch_ID[i], 24);
              New_State[i] = 1;
              New_JustChanged[i] = 1;
        }
        if (Switch_Mode[i] == 1 && Switch_AlarmOFF[i] == 1 && Switch_State[i] == 1 && Switch_JustChanged[i] == 1) {
              mySwitch315.send(Switch_ID[i], 24);
              New_State[i] = 0;
              New_JustChanged[i] = 0;
        }
      }
      Serial.println(Switch_ID[0]);
      Serial.println(Switch_Mode[0]);
      Serial.println(Switch_State[0]);
      Serial.println(Switch_AlarmOn[0]);
      Serial.println(Switch_AlarmOFF[0]);
      Serial.println(Switch_JustChanged[0]);
      Serial.println(New_JustChanged[0]);
      Serial.println(New_State[0]);

    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    //How to send back ? ....
    //Post_Response_Data(Switch_ID[], Switch_AlarmON[], Switch_AlarmOFF[], New_JustChanged[], New_State[]);
```

this my my "outputState" in the monitor :

```
OutputState ( {ID Key:[Switch ID, State, Mode, AlarmON, AlarmOFF,JustChanged]}

{"3038947":["3038947","0","0","0","0","0"],"3038948":["3038948","0","0","0","0","0"]}
```

How can i construct a JSON from the arrays : Switch_ID[],  ... so i can send it back to the server.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys()` to iterate over keys and transform array in `object`. In each loop you can get the data from array e populate the new object.

See the example

```js
let sample = {"3038947":["3038947","0","0","0","0","0"],"3038948":["3038948","0","0","0","0","0"]};

let output = {};

Object.keys(sample).forEach(key => {
   if(!output[key]) output[key] = {};
   let arr = sample[key];
   output[key] = {
      switchId: arr[0],
      state: arr[1],
      mode: arr[2],
      alarmOn: arr[3],
      alarmOff: arr[4],
      justChanged: arr[5]
   };
});


console.log(output); // {"3038947":{"switchId":"3038947","state":"0","mode":"0","alarmOn":"0","alarmOff":"0","justChanged":"0"},"3038948":{"switchId":"3038948","state":"0","mode":"0","alarmOn":"0","alarmOff":"0","justChanged":"0"}}
```